SCAP Compliance Checker 5.9 - Unable to load Ubuntu DIS STIG 22.04
I am trying to import/load DISA STIG Ubuntu 22.04 found on the STIG Library but it keeps giving out about the content type. https://dl.dod.cyber.mil/wp-content/uploads/stigs/zip/U_CAN_Ubuntu_22-04_LTS_V1R1_STIG.zip .... I also ran a content update on the 5.9 client and Ubuntu 22.04 does not show on the list even with DIS STIG Ubuntu 22.04 being available today. Anyone have any ideas about how i can get this resolved?
